# Why there are multiple “/envs” folders in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been using Anaconda (specifically for Spyder) on Windows x64 for some time, however only lately I've tried to do basic stuff regarding using prompt. Why are there many directories that store environments?

After typing `conda info` there are multiple locations listed. As for my understanding creating new enviroment equals creating new directory under `/envs`, however there are three such folders in existence. In `#user\Anaconda\envs`, in `#user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs` and in `#user\.conda\envs` Why?

Comment: First, while well intentioned this question is a conversation with three questions. Basic advice? You have two separate questions here: Question 1 and 2. Also, the second sentence of your opening paragraph that states, “I've generated several questions…” is not needed. Ditto to the 3rd question where you are asking if it’s okay to ask a question. I would recommend you clearly edit this question to focus on question 1. Then start a new question for question 2.

Comment: Thank you for helpful remarks, all I can say is "sorry, I'm new here" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered on conda's Github repository https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5388

There are multiple "\envs" folders to guarantee for at least one user-writable location for the package cache ("pkgs" directory) and the "envs" directory, where new named environments are created.

Best, Gregor